# Update view parameter without redirecting the page

Tags: jsf-2, viewparams

Is it possible to update view parameter without redirecting the page? For instance

I have a managed bean which checks if an ID exist

```
public void signIn(){
    Client c = clientFacade.loginDetail(client.getID());

    if (c != null) {
        loggedIn = true;  
    }
    else{
        loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

and a view which renders just fine if the ID exist.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not applicationManager.loggedIn}">
    <p:commandLink value="Sign In" onclick="loginDialog.show()" styleClass="login-link"></p:commandLink>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{applicationManager.loggedIn}">
    <p:menuButton value="#{applicationManager.client.firstname}" />
</h:panelGroup>

<p:dialog widgetVar="loginDialog" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        ID :    <p:inputText value="#{applicationManager.client.id}" />
        <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{applicationManager.signIn()}" update=":loginForm" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Is it possible to insert the code below at the top of the view and still have an update on the url?

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="input" value="#{applicationManager.client.id}" />
    <f:event listener="#{applicationManager.signIn()}" type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>
```

I tried it, but it's not working, so I guess I might be missing something or doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "update on the URL"? When you add the `preRenderView` what happens (or doesn't)?

Comment: What i meant was that the URL was suppose to change with some new param. For instance, i was expecting to see  "?input=123" at the end of the URL . But it does not change.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you're requesting a URL, but generally, you should add `includeViewParams=true` to the end of the request URL to have the parameter appended to the URL

Comment: Thank for your response but "includeViewParams=true" doesn't work on a <p:commandButton/> it only works on <p:button/> or <h:link/>.